# Is there a Video converter, that can convert like the reference file?

Tags: video, conversion

I have a  video file, with this details:
[image]

I have another video (in .avi format) and want to convert to exactly like this format... Is there any Video Converter, that can convert to the file, exactly as Reference file?

Comment: Manually, yes. Automatically? Not that I know of.

Comment: @Mulvya thanks. Can you tell me how to do that manually? which program can adjust every details so accurately? 
i tried handbrake, ANY Vid converter and etc.. none of them have so many customizable details..

Comment: If you want to encode to AVC, x264 or ffmpeg - there are a couple of features only adjustable in the former, but the important ones can be adjusted in ffmpeg.

Comment: thanks @Mulvya.  

if you'll post all of these as answer, I'll upvote.  p.s. yet, I dont know what commands to use with ffmpeg to achieve desired result.

Comment: If you reveal which properties you want to copy, I can provide a command for that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no "make like this one" option, but seeing the options of the reference file, many apps allow you to make a template for batch exporting, e.g. https://documentation.apple.com/en/compressor/usermanual/index.html#chapter=1%26section=2%26tasks=true

Comment: @T.Todua Handbrake... also MPEGstreamclip & FFMPEG can be batch scripted if you feel comfy w/line commands

Comment: Prolly best to post a new question and ask: how i i do X to Y to make Z with ffmpeg? Also post what u have tried so far. Best!

Comment: & dont forget to accept an answer & upvote useful ones! :)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer already and I'll select the best one a bit later... p.s. i'ts better to remove the first-two comment and embed that into the answer.